# No se controlo managementException WPF

Tags: wpf

estoy tratando de obtener el porcentaje de la bateria de mi laptop, con el siguiente codigo:

using System.Windows.Threading;

using System.Management.Instrumentation;

using System.Diagnostics;

using System.Management;

```
private void bateria()
    {
        ManagementClass wmi = new ManagementClass("win32_battery");
        var baterias = wmi.GetInstances();
        foreach (var bateriass in baterias)
        {

            por = Convert.ToInt32(bateriass["por"]);
            label2.Content = por;
        }
    }
```

Pero me sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya tengo la referencia de "system.management" agregada
Apreciaria mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has probado a utilizar una clase del propio Windows Forms que se llama: [PowerStatus](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.powerstatus?view=netcore-3.1)?

Para poder utilizar dicha clase, tendrías que hacerlo de esta forma (En tu caso):

```
private void bateria()
    {
        ManagementClass wmi = new ManagementClass("win32_battery");
        var baterias = wmi.GetInstances();
        foreach (var bateriass in baterias)
        {
            PowerStatus pwr = SystemInformation.PowerStatus;
            por = pwr.BatteryLifePercent.ToString("P0");
            label2.Content = por;
        }
    }
```

Para poder utilizar dicha clase tendras que hacer un:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Input;
```

La clase de PowerStatus tiene 5 parámetros con los que puedes "jugar":

- **PowerLineStatus** : Estado actual de la alimentación del sistema actual.

  ```
  (Devuelve una Enumeración con: Offline = 0, Online = 1, Unknown = 255)
  ```
- **BatteryChargeStatus**: Estado actual de carga de la batería.

  ```
  (Devuelve una Enumeración con: High = 1, Low =2, Critical = 4, Charging = 
       8, NoSystemBattery = 128, Unknown = 255)
  ```
- **BatteryFullLifetime**:  Duración de la batería principal **en segundos**

  ```
   (Devuelve un entero indicando la duracion en segundos. Devuelve -1 si se desconoce la duración)
  ```
- **BatteryLifePercent**: Cantidad aproximada de lo que queda de carga de la batería.

  ```
    (Devuelve un float que va desde 0,0 a 1,0)
  ```
- **BatteryLifeRemaining**: Número aproximado de segundos de tiempo restante de la batería.

  ```
     (Devuelve un entero aproximándose a los segundos que quedan de batería, o -1 si es desconocida)
  ```

PD: Te recomiendo que utilices los [Binding](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding?view=netcore-3.1) para poder hacer enlaces sin hacer referencia a los "objetos" mediante nombres.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, tu codigo me ha servido de maravilla.

Comment: De nada, y espero que te vaya todo bien!
Si tienes alguna otra duda, solo pregunta que para eso estamos